# Error in running code with R pipeline using dplyr library

Tags: r, pipeline

I'm working on a dataset (olympics) and I would like to create a sub_dataset with specific conditions. To do that I'm using the dplyr library and the code works. The problem is that if I change the code using `%>%` to make it more readable it doesn't work anymore. I've pasted the code below:

```
combination <- select(olympics, Sex, Season, Sport)

M_Summer <- combination %>%
  filter(Sex == "M", Season == "Summer") %>%
  mutate(Num_Sports = length(unique(M_Summer[["Sport"]]))) %>%
  select(-c(Sport))
```

If I run the code above, R shows this error message:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: object 'M_Summer' not found.
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the dataframe in piping which is not yet created hence you are getting error. We need to break the code in two parts so that first part of the code will create dataframe and second part of the code will use the dataframe created by first part.

```
M_Summer <- combination %>%
filter(Sex == "Men", Season == "Summer")
####Break the code    
M_Summer <-M_Summer %>% mutate(Num_Sports = length(unique(M_Summer$Sport))) %>%
select(-c(Sport))
```

Request you to provide head(df) of your data or reproducible example for more accurate code. Do let me know in case you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be specific without more info, but you're trying to use the M-Summer dataframe in the function that makes the dataframe.
The best option might be to split it into two commands;

```
M_Summer <- combination %>%
  filter(Sex == "M", Season == "Summer") 
M_Summer <- mutate(Num_Sports = length(unique(M_Summer[["Sport"]]))) %>%
  select(-c(Sport))
```

Basically, you can't reference the dataframe until after you have actually created it.